# if i pass iteration variable of ng-repeat into a function, it shows as undefined in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to iterate an array like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="xx in dish">
        <li>{{xx.name}}</li>
        <li>{{xx.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

the array is like this:

```
$scope.dish=[
                         {
                           name:'Burger',
                           category: 'mains',
                           label:'Hot',
                           price:'4.99',
                           description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comment: ''
                        },

                        {
                           name:'Sandwich',
                           category: 'mains',
                           label:'Normal',
                           price:'4.99',
                           description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comment: ''
                        }
       ]
```

now i want to use the 'xx' iteration variable i used in ng-repeat, as a variable in a function which i can use in ng-click to get value of array, like this:

```
$scope.makedish = function(xx){

            //this.dish1 = xx;
            $log.log(xx);
        }
```

now when i invoke this makedish function in click like this:

```
<button ng-click="makedish();">click</button>
```

the xx shows as undefined. please help.

Comment: How about passing the argument that the function expects: `ng-click="makedish(xx)"`? Also, wince you have an array of dishes, that thus contains several dishes, why not rename `dish` to `dishes` and `xx`to `dish`? Code is much easier to understand when things are named correctly. And while you're at it, rename makedish() to makeDish().

Comment: Where you written that `ng-click="makedish();"` function call?

Comment: I tried using ng-click="makedish(xx)" but no effect. Will keep in mind about the naming thing, but my question remains.

Comment: in passed ng-click="makedish()" in a button. th fill html is:

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="conFusionappCtrl">
  
  <ul ng-repeat="xx in dish">
  <li>{{xx.name}}</li>
  <li>{{xx.label}}</li>
  <li> {{xx}}
  <a ng-click="makedish(xx)">flflfl</a>
  </li>
  </ul> 

<button ng-click="makedish(xx.name);">vlick</button>  
            </div>

Comment: In your code provided in quetion, you are invoking function without parameters(`makedish()`). Call it with parameter(`makedish(xx)`).

Comment: You use `xx` outside of the ng-repeat defining this variable. So that can't possibly work. `xx` doesn't exist where makedish() is called. Which of the two dishes should be made when clicking on the button? This code should be in the question, BTW, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you have in your comment:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="conFusionappCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="xx in dish">
        <li>{{xx.name}}</li>
        <li>{{xx.label}}</li>
        <li> {{xx}} <a ng-click="makedish(xx)">flflfl</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="makedish(xx.name);">vlick</button>
</div>
```

The reason why this doesn't work is that the call to makedish on the button click is outside the ng-repeat. Try this instead:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="conFusionappCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="xx in dish">
        <ul>
            <li>{{xx.name}}</li>
            <li>{{xx.label}}</li>
            <li> {{xx}} <a ng-click="makedish(xx)">flflfl</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="makedish(xx.name);">vlick</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thansk for he answer, i figured and solved that before..but thanks anyway.

Comment: If it answers your question then you should still mark it as so